# How do you set up a pure emacs layered tty stack with 256 colors and mouse support?

Tags: terminal, tty, emacs24, xterm, 256color

### I use this layered tty stack to reach emacs on GNU/Linux:

```
Mac OS X > iTerm2 $ ssh head-node --> 
$ screen $ ssh compute-node --> 
$ screen $ emacs -nw
```

Notes:

- Mac OS X = Version 10.8.2
- iTerm2 = iterm2.com Build 1.0.0.20130319, terminal type = xterm-256color.
- screen = GNU Screen, built from git clone git://git.savannah.gnu.org/screen.git with --enable-colors25, run with .screenrc "term xterm-256color"
- emacs = Emacs 24.3 built from 24.3 source.

This actually works great, but there are user interface behaviors that I want to modify.

I figure this might be easier if I switch to ...

### A pure emacs layered tty stack with 256 colors and mouse support:

```
Mac OS X > emacs M-x term $ ssh head-node -->
$ [emacs --daemon] emacsclient -nw M-x term $ ssh compute-node -->
$ [emacs --daemon] emacsclient -nw
```

### Which raises these questions ...

1. What is the best choice for emacs terminal emulation in this situation?
2. How do I set up TERM and TERMINFO to get 256 colors?
3. How do I capture/restore window layout in the emacs daemons?
4. How do I keep track of session context? By this I mean hostname and sub-sessions?
5. How do I make the mouse work top-to-bottom?

The mouse actually works fine with iTerm2 and this in ~./emacs:

```
;; Enable iTerm2 mouse support
;; > Preferences > Profiles > Default > Terminal > Enable xterm mouse reporting > check
(unless window-system
  (require 'mouse)
  (xterm-mouse-mode t)
  (global-set-key [mouse-4] '(lambda ()
                              (interactive)
                              (scroll-down 1)))
  (global-set-key [mouse-5] '(lambda ()
                              (interactive)
                              (scroll-up 1)))
  (defun track-mouse (e))
  (setq mouse-sel-mode t)
)
```

This leads to a sub-question...

1a. Is there an emacs terminal emulation that produces/forwards xterm mouse events?

Notes:

- posed as a group because answers must work together.
- tty solutions are required due to bandwidth and personal preference.
- emacs tramp is not sufficient, given various other requirements.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `screen-256color` would be preferable in your `.screenrc`

Comment: @demure Thanks. Could you please elaborate on why you think this and, if you know, tell me where to find a definitive screen-256color source? It's not in git://git.savannah.gnu.org/screen.git and there are multiple versions out there, so I am confused.

Comment: I've had difficulty finding an article directly addressing why using a screen based termcap is preferable, the many sections of the man page suggest it helps with the correct emulation of various features. https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Term.html

Comment: Thanks @demure. Since iterm->ssh->screen->ssh->screen->emacs works perfectly using xterm-256color, I don't see the need to switch to screen-256color.

Comment: I have been working with Emacs for Mac OS X for a while (even with tramp) and it is been a surprisingly good experience. I do not know exactly why you don't want to use tramp, but you could try this native emacs for OSX and connect through ssh directly.